# react-dom installed, but not found. `Could not find module in path: 'react-dom/client' relative to`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, codesandbox

[Here is the Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reproduce-v7-1j4342?file=/package.json)

I want to run a rest, but the `Tests` tab shows this error.

```
Could not find module in path: 'react-dom/client' relative to
'/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/@testing-library/react.esm.js'
```

I referred to these but they did NOT solve my problem.

1. Reinstalling it in the `devDependencies` https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2276
2. Turning off my UBlock origin. https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/529
3. Trying different browsers

What should I do to successfully run this test?

[image]

Comment: Please show some code. This should have nothing to do with how you're interacting with CSB (browser, adblocker, etc).

Comment: @code I provided the Codesandbox link at the top. Is it accessible?

Comment: Did you solve this? Hard to tell from the current status of the sandbox. I've got a similar problem, and the only suggestion I've found so far is to roll back `@testing-library/react` to v12.

Comment: @tim.rohrer Apparently it is a known issue. You will need to use Terminal. I asked the further question for the clarification https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/6599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue.
The answer says you need to use a Terminal to run this. Terminal is just below the preview window.

https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/6599

> Hey @eps1lon - Thank you for flagging this, the tests unfortunately don't work within Server sandboxes and we'll be removing them soon.
> To run the tests you'll need to use the terminal. Sorry for the trouble!